# compare available list with chosen ids in shell script

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a log file containing events where a user has chosen a certain ID, which I want to parse to create a summary.

For every event, the file contains the list of IDs available for the user in single lines starting with the keyword `Available`, and at the end the ID the user ultimately chose, in a line starting with the keyword `Chosen`. Below is an example

```
Available for user:75=1654 at Time=5504.09 
Chosen by user:75=1655

Available for user:10=1300 at Time=550.09
Available for user:10=1301 at Time=550.09
Available for user:10=1303 at Time=550.09
Chosen by user:10=1301
```

In the example, we see that the user `75` has chosen the ID `1655` although only `1654` was shown as `Available` at that time. At a different time, we see that the user `10` had ID options `1300`, `1301` and `1303` to choose from, and selected `1301`.

Note that there may be more than one such event logged for every user; some users may have hundreds of such choice events logged for them.

**The question is:** How can we count the occurence of those events and print a summary based on the log file. I want to print for every user a summary of how often that user chose an ID that was available to him, and how often he chose one that was *not* available.

The output would ideally look like

```
User 1 chose 103 ids from list and 23 not from list
User 2 chose 31 ids from list and 6 not from list
...
```

I have tried with `grep` but was not able to store the list of available IDs each time and compare with chosen one. But any solution with `grep`, `awk` or `sed` is welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `user:75=1300` instead of `user:10=1300`?

Comment: What's the relevance of the `at Time=5504.09` is any?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes you are right its user:10=1300, i mentioned wrong stating example. Time is just to know when it had these options to choose from

Comment: Is 'Availabe' a typo when you wrote this question, or is that in your input file too? Also, please show exactly what the output should be.

Comment: @seshoumara Thanks for the reply. Available is present in the input file. Out should be like xxx (like total 100) ids were chosen from list and yyy (30) ids were chosen not from list or if possible User 1 chose xxx ids from list and yyy not from list upto Nth user chose xxx ids from list and yyy ids not from list. xxx and yyy represent any number of ids chosen from list and not from list respectively. 1 to N could be the total users like from 1 to 80 or else.

Comment: Don't show output or other relevant information in comments - add it to your question so no-one misses it and you can format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sed script:

```
/^Avail/{
    s/[^=]*=([^ ]*).*/\1/;H
}
/^Chosen/{
    s/.*=//;G;h;x;y/\n/,/
    s/,/ is ab in /;s/$/,/
    /(.*) is.*,\1,/s/ab/pre/
    s/(ab|pre) in ,(.*),/\1sent in \2/
    p;s/.*//;x
}
```

**Output**: custom format (wasn't specified by OP)

```
sesh@pc:~/unix$ sed -nrf script.sed input.txt
1655 is absent in 1654
1301 is present in 1300,1301,1303
```

Counting in sed is very difficult. You can pipe `grep -c absent` for example, to count all events where the user selected an ID not present in the available IDs.

Comment: You should mention which sed version(s) that'll work in. I'm guessing maybe just GNU sed but idk. Also any time you find yourself piping sed to grep or sed to sed or grep to sed or grep to grep or similar you should just be using awk instead.

Comment: @EdMorton I always had GNU/Linux distros, so I wouldn't know if my script works in other sed (OS) versions. I had this type of comment before, but why isn't common to request what sed, awk, etc the OP has? Regarding awk, you're right, but I barely know it.

Comment: I just noticed you have `-r` (`-E` is better) so it's definitely GNU-only. Almost every sed script I see posted that uses more than s, g, and p (with -n) is non-portable, and usually GNU-only. Running GNU sed with `--posix` isn't even a guarantee that the script in question is portable because it can be relying on behavior that isn't defined by POSIX. So if you don't KNOW that it's portable the best you can do is always say it's tested using GNU sed in your answers. You can ask what tools versions the OP has but we're not just posting answers for the specific OP so it's not 100% relevant.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're looking for, without the expected output it's a guess but hopefully you can massage to suit:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[:= ]" }
$1 == "Chosen" {
    if ( $5 in avail ) {
        availCnt++
        str = ""
    }
    else {
        notAvailCnt++
        str = " not"
    }
    userCnt++
    printf "User %s chose %s which was%s available\n", $4, $5, str
    delete avail
    next
}
NF { avail[$5] }
END {
    printf "%d users chose available %d times and not available %d times\n", userCnt, availCnt, notAvailCnt
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
User 75 chose 1655 which was not available
User 10 chose 1301 which was available
2 users chose available 1 times and not available 1 times
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.

Comment: You may want to add that for those `awk` implementations that don't support the `delete` statement without array index, one workaround is to use `split("",avail)`, as suggested in the [GNU Awk Users Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Delete).

Comment: There are no remaining awk implementations that don't support the `delete` statement. It's been part of POSIX for almost 10 years and was supported by all major awk implementations for years before that. If you're running a version of awk that doesn't support it then you're WAY overdue to update your awk version.